# Working with json.net/vb or c# and Fiddler attempting to scrape content

Tags: screen-scraping

I've been working on this for days now and just can not wrap my head around it.

Straight up I am trying to grab prices from a big box store and failing, I can get all other content using the htmlagilitypack no problem but they use a json api to display the price tag.

I am using Fiddler and I am seeing the flow of data. In the Fiddler results I can see the json content coming back with the prices and the header information being passed,  but I just can't seem to put any code together that would remotely work to get the same data that Fiddler sees.

Please, any pointers would be greatly appreciated, or even some online tutorials. I don't expect anyone to work this for me, I just need a starting point.

This is the page I am trying to get the price from.

http://www.walmart.ca/en/ip/10321728

Just an fyi, this is for my own purposes only, I search daily for pricing on products on several different sites and I am trying to just display the pricing on my own localhost from a few different sites.

Comment: If you can post the code that is stripping out the JSON etc. already, it will probably be easier for someone to suggest how to continue from there.

Comment: Hey Octopoid, I haven't even got anything started yet for working with json to get the pricing. I can't find anything for online tutorials or help on how to start with this. I've read through the json documentation and understand how to work with the returning json, but I have no idea how to get the returning json to start with. I don't think posting my htmlagilitypack code that gets the page content with an empty price div would help at all.

Comment: I may still have misunderstood exactly where the issue begins, but - `I can see the json content coming back`. I assume this means you have a URL that you can use to request JSON. Look into [HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in order to pull that back as a string, you should find plenty of simple tutorials / examples. Once you have the JSON into a string, you can use JSON.NET to turn it into a structure you should be able to easily work with.

Comment: Sorry Octopid what I was referring to when I say I can see the json content coming back is I can see it in Fiddler when I run the above page and go through the results in Fiddler. I updated my post to be a little more clear about that.